# Opening an SSH session in Python with only standard libraries

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to fix a segment of code originally developed in Python 2.X.  I have to use all standard libraries, , remove paramiko, and need to keep the functionality the same.  As you can see, there is a port number configuration, username, password, etc.  Any suggestions?

I have tried other SSH options, but none have worked.  It returns an error.

```
def grab_and_post_inventory_data(machine_name):
try:
    if not USEKEYFILE?: ssh.connect(str(machine_name), port=PORT, username=USER, password=PASSWORD, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    else: ssh.connect(str(machine_name), port=PORT, username=USER, key_filename=KEY_FILE, timeout=TIMEOUT)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print(machine_name + ': authentication failed')
    return None
except Exception as err:
    print(machine_name + ":" + err)
    return  None
devargs = {}
```

The output is an error, saying ssh not defined.  There is no ssh library.  I have tried other solutions, but no avail.  Any ideas?  Again, I need to use only the standard library and remove paramiko.

Comment: If you don't have an `ssh` library, the only thing I can think of is to run the `ssh` command using the `subprocess` library. Don't even think of trying to implement the SSH protocol yourself using sockets.

Comment: What would be the best way to implement the username, password, port, etc. into the subprocess?  Could you give an example?

Comment: Username and port can be specified as arguments to the `ssh` command. Password is best avoided by using public key authentication. The whole thing will be complicated if you need to parse prompts, that's why they write libraries for it.

Answer (score 0):

**subprocess.Popen()**
It is to control a local ssh session using subprocess.Popen() if no libraries are available. This is a super primative way to do things, and not recommended if you can avoid it.

```
import subprocess
import sys

HOST="www.example.org"
# Ports are handled in ~/.ssh/config since we use OpenSSH
COMMAND="uname -a"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result
```

but recommended way is to use paramiko for ssh client and server. it will handle all low level operations. it is very simple to use.

Comment: Thanks!  I need to be able to argue a password too.